# Nack and reject on RabbitMQ

Tags: queue, rabbitmq, message-queue

I want to handle unsuccessful messages the consumer gets from the queue and re-queue them.

Imagine I have a situation like this:

```
P => | foo | bar | baz | => C
```

Where foo, bar and baz are messages.

If consumer reads `baz` but something goes wrong, I can either use the `basic.reject` or the `basic.nack` ( https://www.rabbitmq.com/nack.html ). Using one of these two commands, I will pass the argument to requeue the message.

The problem is the message is requeued in the same position it was before, so the next message will be `baz` again.

I would like to requeue it but send it back to the beginning of the queue:

```
P => | baz | foo | bar | => C
```

I solved it with some lines of code on my application, but I wonder if a better solution exists, maybe using some functionality of RabbitMQ directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can take a look on the Dead Letter Queue(DLQ): https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html

Comment: Yes, I read the whole documentation yesterday. This is not what I was looking for, but apparently what I was looking for does not exist and the dead letter queue can be a good workaround.

Comment: Here queue(FIFO) behaves exactly as expected, as you are using manual ack mode the thread will wait untill getting an ack, as it fail to process so it will try to put in same position in a loop manner. On the other hand processing a bad message again and again doesn't make sense. Retry for 2-3 time(spring-amqp has direct support) if still fails then deadletter it so that later you can analysis the pattern of bad message and directly reach out to client team.

Comment: may be you can add TTL to your failed messages and put in DLX, so once it expired it will automatically move to main queue.